# Click and drag cell content insertion jQWidgets datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable

Its possible Click and drag cell content insertion jQWidgets datatables

Answer (score 0):

jQWidgets have a demo which implements Drag and Drop of Grid Cells. You can find it on this page [jQWidgets Grid Drag and Drop](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/dragdrop.htm?arctic)